# How to get extensions for VSCodium behind proxy?

Tags: proxy, text-editor

I am trying to use [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com/) behind a corporate proxy that uses a self-signed certificate.
I have `"http.proxyStrictSSL": false` configured in my `settings.json` and VSCodium inherits from `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` according to the hint on the settings-page:

> The proxy setting to use. If not set, will be inherited from the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables.

I can confirm with `echo $http_proxy` that both variables are set.

When I click on the extensions-Button it takes a long time and then I see the following error:

> ⓧ Error while fetching extensions. XHR failed

Can anyone suggest how to debug the connection or any known solution?